# wiremock compatibility with jetty9

Tags: java, junit, jetty-9, wiremock

I am trying to use wiremock (testCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.1.4-rc3') in to execute JUnit tests in a webapp which is using 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.6.v20151106' as a gradle dependency.

When I run Junit tests, I get an error and wiremock 2.1.4-rc3 doesn't seem to be compatible with jetty9...

[Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getUri()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpURI;]

Full Stack:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getUri()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpURI;
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHttpServletRequestAdapter.isBrowserProxyRequest(WireMockHttpServletRequestAdapter.java:219)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.verification.LoggedRequest.createFrom(LoggedRequest.java:59)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AdminRequestHandler.handleRequest(AdminRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AbstractRequestHandler.handle(AbstractRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.service(WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a Jetty server compatibility problem.

You're using Jetty 9.3.6.v20151106, WireMock 2.1.4-rc3 depends on Jetty 9.2.13.v20150730.

This method was removed and doesn't exist on `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` in Jetty 9.3.6.

```
public org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI getUri();
```

The easiest solution is to downgrade the version of Jetty you're using, and use the same version as WireMock.  Alternatively, you could fork WireMock and upgrade the version of Jetty you're using.  Doesn't sound optimal?  There has already been discussion about refactoring WireMock to handle this better: https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/pull/442

Comment: I had the same issue fixed it upgrading wiremock:
testCompile('com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.5.1')